# How can I get the deg^-1 symbol with siunitx package?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx, degrees

I need the following symbol:
[image]

I tried with:

```
\SI[]{5.73}{\per\deg}
```

But I want the negative power!

Can you help me?

Comment: Just a curiosity. Where have you seen deg^-1 and what is the significance?

Comment: `\qty{30}{deg^{-1}}`  (using `siunitx` v3), however, as said @Sebastiano, what is meaning/ significance of this unit?

Comment: I have to use it to indicate the slope of lift coefficient.

Comment: For example 5.4 1/deg.

Comment: @Giuseppe Looking on Wikipedia I see, lift slope is π^2/90 ≃ 0.11 per degree. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_coefficient

Comment: In my case, for C-130J aircraft, it is 5.73 per degree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The desired behavior is the default bahavior but it does not seem to be working for `\deg`. However, if you manually declare the unit

```
\DeclareSIUnit{\deg}{deg}
```

it seems to work just fine:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\DeclareSIUnit{\deg}{deg}% <-- No exponent if this is not inclued

\begin{document}
$\SI{5.73}{\per\deg}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: I think `\deg` doesn't work as expected here is because it isn't actually a unit defined by `siunitx`. `\deg` is just the LaTeX default degree function (like `\exp`). With `\DeclareSIUnit{\deg}{deg}` you turn `\deg` into a `siunitx` unit.

Comment: @moewe: Ahhh, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanantion.